# MySQL self-join to get two geographically closest items with different properties?

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, self-join

We have a single table of weather markers on a map, where each marker type is either wind or cloud.

For each cloud marker we want to find the "WindDir" field value for the closest wind marker. It seems like a self-join would do the trick, but constructing the query is proving difficult.

Below is our incorrect pseudo SQL. We know the Distance value will be what we want. We just need to how to make the query find the closest wind marker for each cloud marker, so that we can get the wind marker's "WindDir" value.

```
SELECT w1.ID AS ID, w1.Lat AS Lat, w1.Lng AS Lng, 
       w2.WindDir AS WindDir, 
       MIN(SQRT(POWER(ABS(w1.Lng - w2.Lng), 2) + POWER(ABS(w1.Lat - w2.Lat), 2))*60) AS Distance 
FROM Weather w1 WHERE w1.Marker="Cloud"
LEFT JOIN Weather w2 WHERE w2.Marker="Wind"
USING ID
```

We'd be grateful for any advice on making a version that works!

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close (basically just reordered for syntax)

```
SELECT w1.ID AS ID, w1.Lat AS Lat, w1.Lng AS Lng, 
       w2.WindDir AS WindDir, 
       (SQRT(POWER(ABS(w1.Lng - w2.Lng), 2) + POWER(ABS(w1.Lat - w2.Lat), 2))*60) AS Distance 
FROM Weather w1 LEFT JOIN Weather w2 USING (ID)
WHERE w1.Marker="Cloud" AND w2.Marker="Wind"
ORDER BY Distance DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Assuming you just want the closest result, I added a `LIMIT 1` to restrict what's returned.

On a side note, this method of finding distance between two lat/lon pairs is unlikely to give you good results for even fairly small changes.  There are methods for approximating these distances...

Comment: Shouldn't the `AND w2.Marker="Wind"` go in the `LEFT JOIN` predicate and not in the `WHERE`?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: I don't believe so, see this syntax reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html. It's possible to use the `ON` conditional rather than the `USING` column expression, but the `WHERE` clause seems appropriate here.

Comment: @mark-e, what i was saying is that it defeats the `LEFT` join, since its filtered in the `WHERE`

Comment: Wow, didn't expect responses this fast (it's my first time here :-)

Comment: @Mark E: your query does not produce error messages, like mine did, however the response is NULL for each field returned, so it's not quite there yet.Yes, we do want only the single closest result. If you have a references for a better method that would be great, but we're not terribly concerned with precision.

Comment: @Ken: you get result rows but all the columns have null values or you get no results?

Comment: @Ken: what happens if you remove the `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Mark: no effect, just one row with all five fields set to NULL - thanks for your continued efforts on this.

Comment: @Ken: updated the query, try the new one and let me know what you get.  Are you sure you have at least one Cloud and one Wind row?

Comment: @Mark: The updated query produces no rows and no errors. There are exactly 1,000 rows in the table for wind markers and 220 rows for cloud markers.